# ClosedInterval<String> different declaration

Tags: ios, swift

These two statemens works fine and return the same value:

```
println(("A"..."Z").contains("B"))
```

and

```
var range = "A"..."Z"
println(range.contains("B"))
```

But if I try this :

```
var c : Character = "B"

var range = "A"..."Z"
//println(range.contains(c))

println(("A"..."Z").contains(c))
```

The commented line output the following error :

```
'Character' is not convertible to 'String'
```

What's going on here? The variable `c` isn't a `Character` type?

Comment: I think it's saying `c` can't be used as a Character for searching in your range of String. Does `range.contains(String(c))` work?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes it does, really I figure out before, but I don't understand why not work, if you see the type in XCode and it's of the type `Character`

Comment: What you're saying doesn't quite make sense. It is Character. That's not the problem. It's that `range` is a String. Apparently, `String.contains()` requires the argument to be a String as well. Hence, it seems like it's complaining that it *is a Character*, when `c` as a Character needs to be cast to a String.

Comment: @JaredFarrish The `range` variable isn't of type `String`, if you see it in XCode it's type is `ClosedInterval<String>`

Comment: The `<String>` indicates it's a String.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that `c` isn't a `Character`, it's that `range` is a `ClosedInterval<String>`.

A string literal like `"A"` can be converted to either a `String` or a `Character` since both implement `ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralConvertible`.

When you define `range` as `"A"..."Z"`, the compiler can't infer how you're going to use `range` later on so just defines it using: `ClosedInterval<String>`.

When you define a range and use it immediately, as in: `("A"..."Z").contains(c)`, the compiler can see that `c` is a `Character` so it creates the range as a `ClosedInterval<Character>`.

You can force `range` to be a `ClosedInterval<Character>` and see that `contains` works for `Character`s:

```
var range: ClosedInterval<Character> = "A"..."Z"
var c : Character = "B"
println(range.contains(c))
```